# ブラウザ内のアクティブなタブで開いているページの URL を取得したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Electron を使って、デスクトップを監視するアプリケーションを作ろうと思っています。
常にデスクトップ上を監視して、ブラウザで開いているページやデスクトップアプリのアクティブ時間の統計を計算するような機能を実装予定なのですが、Electron でこれらの機能を実現することは可能でしょうか。